# How can I get the type of a field using Twig?

Tags: templating, field, fieldtypes

I would like to loop through all the fields of a field layout tab form the current entry.

This is working fine to get the field name and value:

```
{% for fieldLayoutField in entry.getFieldLayout().getFields() if fieldLayoutField.tabId == 50 %}
    {% set field = craft.app.fields.getFieldById(fieldLayoutField.id) %}
    Field name: {{ field.name }}
    Field value: entry[field.handle]
{% endfor %}
```

But I need to go a step further, by checking the field type, and then handle something different depending of the type.

Example:

```
{% if field.type == 'dropdown' %}
    <select>
        {% for option in field.options %}
            <option value="{{ option.value }}">
                {{ option.label }}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
{% endif %}
```

As `{{ field.type }}` and `{{ entry[field.handle].type }}` aren't defined, I can't guess properly when this is, for example, a Plain Text field or a Dropdown field.

I could guess some fields type, by some checks like bellow, but it sounds very dirty:

- `field.columnType`
  returns `text` if a Plain Text field.
- `field.options | length` returns `true` if a Dropdown field.

For some others, like the Lightswitch field, I don't know exactly how to guess the type properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [className](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/functions.html#classname-object) function

```twig
{% switch className(field) %}
    {% case 'craft\\fields\\PlainText' %}
    {% case 'craft\\fields\\Dropdown' %}
```